# Have nested lists line up with skewed parent

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a vertical navigation that is in a skewed parent div. My goal is to have all the list items follow the same path as the edge of the parent div, I'm not quite certain how to go about it.

I typed up a sample in codepen showing the default behaviour.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWYQmd

```
<div class="parent">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a>text</a></li>
    <li><a>text</a></li>
    <li><a>menu</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a>text</a></li>
        <li><a>text</a></li>
        <li><a>menu</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a>text</a></li>
            <li><a>text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ul>
</div>

.parent {
  background: rgba(123,23,55,0.2);
  width: 500px;
  text-align: right;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
.submenu{
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

Any tips to make it line up like I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from 'unskewing' the `li` elements: in the case the `li` element has another `ul`, then the whole block becomes unskewed.

What you need to do is 'unskew' only the content of the `li`, not the `li` itself. Assuming all your text will be within an `a` tag, then just replace your 'unskew' with:

```
li a{
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skew(20deg);  
}
```

See result here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjyzYq

Comment: Simple and effective. Thank you very much!